# I have Windows servers in the cloud. How can I tell if WSUS will help me save money?

Tags: amazon-ec2, azure, wsus

I have Windows Servers in the cloud. (amazon, Azure, etc).

Wil WSUS will help me save money on bandwidth transfer costs? Have any prior studies been done for this specific use case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not charged for inbound bandwidth on [EC2](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/) or [Azure](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/data-transfers/), so WSUS will not matter in this regards.

That said, there are other significant benefits of WSUS that you should consider when making your go/no-go decision.

> Have any prior studies been done for this specific use case?

This is not a complex enough subject to warrant a study.